# Perl Twig Delete not working as expected

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to delete a node using XML::TWig my code is as follows;-

```
    my $cfg = shift;    
    my $version = '6.0';    
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
    my $file_loc = catfile( home_directory_path(), "Builds","data.xml" );
    $twig->parsefile("$file_loc");

for my $number ( $twig->findnodes('/Install/version/number') ) {
  $number->parent->delete if $number->trimmed_text eq $version;
}

    open my $xml_fh, '>', "$file_loc" or die $!;
    $twig->set_pretty_print('indented_c');
    $twig->print($xml_fh);
    close $xml_fh;
```

and my xml is like this.

```
<Install>
  <version>
    <number>7.0</number>
    <build>build</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>kind</kind>
  </version>
    <version>
    <number>6.0</number>
    <build>build</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>kind</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

I am trying to delete the version node if the number matches.

It is working fine when the xml has only one node like:-

```
 <Install> 
        <number>6.0</number>
        <build>build</build>
        <path>path</path>
        <kind>kind</kind>
      </version>
    </Install>
```

In this case it will delete 6.0 from version node but if there are more than 1 version node as in the first case then it is not deleting it.

The expected output in first case is.

```
 <Install> 
   <version>
    <number>7.0</number>
    <build>build</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>kind</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

it is giving error "panic: attempt to copy freed scalar 491b4d8 to 2c52da0".It parse first node that is 7.0 and returns the above error same thing is happening if I swap the position of nodes.

Comment: So, just to clarify - your first XML snippet _isn't_ working? Because my test case works fine.

Comment: Is it the problem with XML ??? @Sobrique

Comment: I don't know - the XML you've posted there works fine.

Answer (score 1):

My test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $version = '6.0';
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented_a' )->parse( \*DATA );

for my $number ( $twig->findnodes('/Install/version/number') ) {
    $number->parent->delete if $number->trimmed_text eq $version;
}

$twig->print;

__DATA__

<Install>
  <version>
    <number>7.0</number>
    <build>1032474</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>RIBS</kind>
  </version>
    <version>
    <number>6.0</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>RIBS</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

Produces:

```
<Install>
  <version>
    <number>7.0</number>
    <build>1032474</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>RIBS</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

I'm not sure what problem you are therefore having. I could only perhaps guess that it's because that literal `eq` doesn't match what you have in your XML file.

So perhaps:

```
if $number -> trimmed_text =~ m/6\.0/;
```

For example?

Comment: This is not a problem with the matching it is giving error "panic: attempt to copy freed scalar 491b4d8 to 2c52da0".It parse first node that is 7.0 and returns the above error same thing is happening if I swap the position of nodes.

Comment: In which case I'd be suggesting checking installed versions - that doesn't look like a problem with the module.